# YouTube HTML Agility Pack C#

Tags: c#, html, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

I am trying to retrieve all the video ids off the YouTube's search results page.

Each result has this code:

```
<a href="/watch?v=aYIC-ebAD3o" class="ux-thumb-wrap result-item-thumb">
  <span class="video-thumb ux-thumb-128 ">
    <span class="clip">
      <img onload="tn_load(5)" alt="Thumbnail" src="//i2.ytimg.com/vi/aYIC-ebAD3o/default.jpg" >
    </span>
  </span>
  <span class="video-time">4:16</span>
  <span dir="ltr" class="yt-uix-button-group addto-container short video-actions" data-video-ids="aYIC-ebAD3o" data-feature="thumbnail">
    <button type="button" class="start master-sprite  yt-uix-button yt-uix-button-short yt-uix-tooltip" onclick=";return false;" title="" data-button-action="yt.www.addtomenu.add" role="button" aria-pressed="false">
      <img class="yt-uix-button-icon yt-uix-button-icon-addto" src="//s.ytimg.com/yt/img/pixel-vfl3z5WfW.gif" alt="">
        <span class="yt-uix-button-content">
          <span class="addto-label">Add to</span>
        </span>
    </button>
    <button type="button" class="end  yt-uix-button yt-uix-button-short yt-uix-tooltip yt-uix-button-empty" onclick=";return false;" title="" data-button-menu-id="shared-addto-menu" data-button-action="yt.www.addtomenu.load" role="button" aria-pressed="false">
      <img class="yt-uix-button-arrow" src="//s.ytimg.com/yt/img/pixel-vfl3z5WfW.gif" alt="">
    </button>
  </span>
  <span class="video-in-quicklist">Added to queue    </span>
</a>
<div class="result-item-main-content">
```

And I am trying to parse out the "data-video-ids" class data. Whats the best way to do this with the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)?

I have tried this:

```
foreach(HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.
    SelectNodes("//span[@class='data-video-ids']"))
{
    string text = node.InnerText;
    lblTest2.Text += text + Environment.NewLine;
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 'data-video-ids' you're trying to filter out is not a class but an attribute - please try out the following expression in SelectNodes:

```
"//span[@data-video-ids]"
```

To retrieve the attribute value you could try this approach (since HtmlAgilityPack doesn't support attribute selection you have to get an element first and then select the actual attribute):

```
foreach(HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.
    SelectNodes("//span[@data-video-ids]"))
{
    var videoIds = node.Attributes["data-video-ids"];
    if (videoIds == null) continue;

    string text = videoIds.Value;
    lblTest2.Text += text + Environment.NewLine;
}
```

Comment: it works but its not retrieving the information i am after. i was hoping for the aYIC-ebAD3o but instead returns add to

Answer (score 5):

I think you will be better off in the longrun if you use one of YouTube's [APIs](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/overview.html).

I would only use web requests and HtmlAgilityPack as a last resort when no API exists.  The main reason for this is if YouTube ever changes their page, it breaks your code.  Open APIs are generally geared to be backwards compatible so your application should work indefinitely in most cases.

Here is a code example from Youtube's API:

```
YouTubeQuery query = new YouTubeQuery(YouTubeQuery.DefaultVideoUri);

//order results by the number of views (most viewed first)
query.OrderBy = "viewCount";

// search for puppies and include restricted content in the search results
// query.SafeSearch could also be set to YouTubeQuery.SafeSearchValues.Moderate
query.Query = "puppy";
query.SafeSearch = YouTubeQuery.SafeSearchValues.None;

Feed<Video> videoFeed = request.Get<Video>(query);

printVideoFeed(videoFeed);
```

Looks simple, right?

Comment: i tried the api but could not get it working. after a user typed in a keyword, i want a list of videos related to that keyword and display the url however I could not get the list of videos displayed.

Comment: I still think you would be greatly better off getting the API to work.  What happens when your code stops working after YouTube changes their HTML?  You fix it.  They change it again?  You fix it... Get the idea?  I would bet there are plenty of resources and examples online to get it working.

Comment: See this url for .Net http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_dotnet.html

Comment: Just keep in mind that they may have a quota limits (max number of requests, limited search results, etc.) on the API which could be an issue for applications doing massive data retrieval (http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/faq.html#quota).

Comment: yea tried that code previously but could not find out away to store the url of each video within the list. it only has meta information like description etc. and how would you go about having each url on a seperate line within a text box from the api. I agree it would be better, I just cant get it working. I got the above post working but would like the api method more.